# html component visible/invisible

Tags: html, components, hide

I need to hide a component html:

```
<div class="hid" >
  <select >
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and I put into a style tag this code:

```
.hid{ display: none;}
```

and it works: the component is hide.

Now I need to make visible the component by button an I put this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
   function do_change(){ 
     document.getElementById("hid").style.display = "block";
   }
</script>

<button onclick="do_change">edit</button>
```

but doesn't work.
I need tyo hide component when the page start and show component when I clik the button whe the page is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `getElementById` but your element doesn't have an id - it has a class. You also need braces in your `onclick` to run the `do_change` function.

```css
#hid {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function do_change() {
    document.getElementById("hid").style.display = "block";
  }
</script>

<button onclick="do_change()">edit</button>

<div id="hid">
  <select>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "`hid`" is a class, so you can't select it with `getElementById()`. You should add unique id to that element.

Alternative way is select by class with `getElementsByClass()`, which returns all elements with defined class, so you need to find right element.

As Turnip said, you need bracket after `do_change`, because it's function. I guess that class "`hid`" should hide all elements, which have that class. That's correct. Selecting by id is easier so I would just add unique id to the element like `id="gender"`. Then the code would look like:

CSS

```
.hid {display: none;}
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function do_change(){ 
      document.getElementById("gender").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="gender" class="hid" >
    <select >
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>

<button onclick="do_change()">edit</button>
```